# how to make /metrics endpoint show the metrics Sorted?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, codahale-metrics

I have a Spring Boot 1.3.1 project. Using actuator, so I have /metrics endpoint too.

I am using codahale to add a metric per some of my methods, and the full java classname is the name of the metric. That is all ok.

But the metrics there show unsorted, it's very inadequate, having all sorted would be much better (max, min, percentiles etc for a given metric will be in a single block, not all over the place as now).

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I did find a solution, quick but not perfect tough: I am using curl | sort. I'll implement your solution when I have time. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this problem.
I add a new Endpoint that call the MetricsEndpoint and sort the result.

```
@Component
public class CustomMetricsEndpoint extends AbstractEndpoint<Map<String, Object>> {

    private MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint;

    @Autowired
    public CustomMetricsEndpoint(MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint) {
        super("custommetrics");
        this.metricsEndpoint = metricsEndpoint;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> invoke() {
        SortedMap<String, Object> metricsMap =
                new TreeMap<String, Object>(this.metricsEndpoint.invoke());
        return metricsMap;
    }

}
```

Now, when I call /custommetrics, the result is sorted by keys.